# Performance - How to get those words in a list of words that matches with a give sentence in R

Tags: regex, r

Am trying to get only those words from a list that are present in a given sentence.The words can **include** **bigram** **words** as well. For example,

```
wordList <- c("really good","better","awesome","true","happy")
sentence <- c("This is a really good program but it can be made better by making it more efficient")
```

myresult should be :

```
"really good" "better"
```

I have **1000 sentences** like this on which i need to compare the words. The **word list** is also **bigger**. i tried brute force method using grep command but it took a lot of time (as expected). I am looking to get the matching words in a way that the performance is better.

Comment: Try the `stringr` package (or `stringi` which `stringr` wraps). For your example `wordList[stringr::str_detect(sentence,wordList)]`.

Comment: @ nicola This approach also takes a lot of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require(dplyr)
wordList <- c("really good","better","awesome","true","happy")
sentence <- c("This is a really good program but it can be made better by making it more efficient")

# get  unigrams  from the sentence
unigrams <- unlist(strsplit(sentence, " ", fixed=TRUE))

# get bigrams from the sentence
bigrams <- unlist(lapply(1:length(words)-1, function(i) {paste(words[i],words[i+1])} ))

# .. and combine into data frame
grams <- data.frame(grams=c(unigrams, bigrams), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# dplyr join should be pretty efficient
matches <- inner_join(data.frame(wordList, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
                      grams,
                      by=c('wordList'='grams'))

matches
     wordList
1 really good
2      better
```

Comment: Clearly the solution from @nicola is way better than my sledgehammer!

Comment: @ epi99 I was able to use your solution by using "match" function  in the place of inner_join as it was faster. I have given my solution below but accepting your answer as it helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use **@epi99**'s answer with a slight modification.

```
wordList <- c("really good","better","awesome","true","happy")
sentence <- c("This is a really good program but it can be made better by making it more efficient")

# get  unigrams  from the sentence
unigrams <- unlist(strsplit(sentence, " ", fixed=TRUE))

# get bigrams from the sentence
bigrams <- unlist(lapply(1:length(unigrams)-1, function(i) {paste(unigrams[i],unigrams[i+1])} ))

# .. and combine into a single vector

grams=c(unigrams, bigrams)

# use match function to get the matching words

matches <- match(grams, wordList )
matches <- na.omit(matches)
matchingwords <- wordList[matches]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
unlist(sapply(wordList, function(x) grep(x, sentence)))
```